# Are two variables dependent if they are both dependent on another variable?

Tags: probability, statistics

If $X$ and $Y$ are dependent and $X$ and $Z$ are also dependent. Are $Y$ and $Z$ dependent?

My answer is Yes. However I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be throwing an even number with your die, $Y$ throwing a $2$ or $4$ with your die, and $Z$ throwing a $2$, $3$ or $6$ with your die.

Which of these are dependent events? Which of them are independent events?

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y$ and $Z$ be iid $N(0,1)$ random variables.  Let $X=Y+Z$.  Since these variables are jointly Gaussian, we can check their dependence or independence by seeing if they are correlated.  Well, $X$ and $Y$ are correlated, as are $X$ and $Z$.  But $Y$ and $Z$ are uncorrelated.